# Regex for String with first two characters fixed and rest digits

Tags: regex, string

Is there a regular expression for? :

- String of length 8
- First two chracters fixed 'UE' or 'ue'
- remaining 6 characters must be digits [0-9]

Eg: https://regex101.com/r/PufypE/1

The expression i tried

```
\^(UE|ue){2}[0-9]{6}\
```

but its not working (no match found!)

Comment: `^(ue)\d{6}$` with `i` modifier. If you want to ensure either uppercase or lowercase is used (so that something like `Ue` is not possible), you can use `^(UE|ue)\d{6}$`

Comment: Updating the regex at the link you've provided with a correct answer: https://regex101.com/r/PufypE/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want:

```
\b(UE|ue)[0-9]{6}\b
```

You don't need the {2} next to the (UE|ue) since you are specifying those exactly.  The \b is a word boundary so this will match a list like you put in the comment: UE123456,ue654321  This is a good site to play with a regex on for this kind of stuff:  http://regex101.com

Comment: it won't match ue128007,UE128007 but it will match one of those like ue128007.  I'll update with something that will match a list

Comment: @wrangler please update your question to include **all** relevant information, such as an actual sample string with multiple values. You've only presented us with a single sample, thus these answers both work on your single sample. Also, you should specify which language you're using. Regex differs from engine to engine.

Comment: Added eg: in the question and your edit worked thanks

Answer (score 1):

Regex should be:

```
^[Uu][Ee][0-9]{6}$
```

`(UE|ue){2}` in your regex would match 2 occurrences of `UE` or `ue`

Comment: @wrangler of course it's not matching. You didn't specify the `m` flag so that it's multiline and you also have extra characters `, ` on the first line